# How to paginate ExpressionEngine {reverse_related_entries}

Tags: expressionengine

I'm surprised I haven't run into this before, or at least I forgot how I got it working.

I have a standard EE relationship field. In this case, I have a "Products" channel, and each product belongs to an entry in the "Designers" channel.

I quite obviously want a page to list all products for a single designer. My first attempt looked like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="designers" url_title="{segment_3}" limit="1"}

    {reverse_related_entries channel="products" limit="15"}
        {snippet_product_grid}
        {snippet_paginate}
    {/reverse_related_entries}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

According to [anecdotal evidence](http://expressionengine.com/legacy_docs/modules/weblog/reverse_related_entries.html#3668) in the EE documentation, you can't paginate reverse related entries. So what's the solution? Is there a way to easily grab all the product entry IDs, given the `url_title` of a designer? Or do I have to resort to using SQL?

Is there any way I could solve this using the [Stash](https://github.com/croxton/Stash) add-on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What janvl said with playa. Using stash, you want to use the dev branch to which Mark Croxton has added a pagination feature for {exp:stash:get_list}

https://github.com/croxton/Stash/tree/dev#expstashget_list-tag-pair

Haven't tested this code on a local sandbox but the code below should get you started

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="designers" url_title="{segment_3}" limit="1"}
    {exp:stash:set_list name="related_products" parse_tags="yes"}
        {reverse_related_entries channel="products"}
            {stash:st_item_title}{title}{/stash:st_item_title}
        {/reverse_related_entries}
    {/exp:stash:set_list}
{/exp:channel:entries}


{exp:stash:get_list name="related_products" parse_tags="yes" parse_conditionals="yes" prefix="my_prefix" paginate="bottom"}

    {if my_prefix:count == 1}<ul>{/if}
        <li>{st_item_title}</li>
    {if my_prefix:count == my_prefix:total_results}</ul>{/if}

    {if my_prefix:no_results}
        <p>No related products</a></p>
    {/if}

    {my_prefix:paginate}
        {pagination_links}
            <ul>
                {first_page}
                        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-first">First Page</a></li>
                {/first_page}

                {previous_page}
                        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-previous">Previous Page</a></li>
                {/previous_page}

                {page}
                        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number} {if current_page}active{/if}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>
                {/page}

                {next_page}
                        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-next">Next Page</a></li>
                {/next_page}

                {last_page}
                        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-last">Last Page</a></li>
                {/last_page}
            </ul>
        {/pagination_links}
    {/my_prefix:paginate}

{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Answer (score 5):

you could use playa to set up your relationships.

As far as I can tell, you should be able to paginate related entries in playa:
https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/pagination_in_playa#reply_6602199

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can paginate Playa relationships because they behave like an embedded second loop pointed to the other channel. So you can either go the stash route (which offers many benefits outside of just this pagination need, of course) or if you convert your relationship field to a Playa field, you can paginate that way as well.